# Node.js/Electron - Can I reset the system idle time?

Tags: node.js, electron

It's quite easy to get the system idle time in Electron with `powerMonitor.getSystemIdleTime()` However, I wonder if there is any easy way to reset this? I tried both the `powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-app-suspension')` and the `powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-display-sleep')` but they don't really reset the idle time.

When I use the Caffeine on the Mac OSX I noticed it works perfectly. It keeps reseting the system idle time.

[image: Caffeine]

Checked into the Caffeine source code. It's written in C#, not sure how can we make it in Node.js/Electron.

```
  internal static class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
    public const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
    public const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
    public const uint ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002;
  }
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: Tried the node-stay-awake package but it didn't work.

Comment: the RobotJS works. I use `robot.keyTap('escape')` to reset the idle time successfully. Not sure if there is a better solution than this one.